# Is WPF MediaElement good for my task

Tags: wpf

I know WPF MediaElement has lots of bugs, but my project is quite simple:
I have two big video files, 500 mb each - same visuals, with different rendered texts - for 2 different languages.

WPF buttons on top of those videos:
'language' - switch visibility of each video, depending on language; 
'product' - scroll forth/back to the required time in both videos simultaneously.

So - all this project does - it plays two video files 24 hours and scrolls both files to reqiured time marks on button click, and shows/hides each video depending on 'language' button click. It does not reload those video files, neither load new ones.

Currently I have this project done with WPFMediaKit. But the problem is - for some reason it has somewhat own time handling. Say I tell it to stop at 23rd second and rewind to 11th - it stops at 24-25 and then rewinds to 11th. I guess its related to its DX renderer.

So my question is - can WPF MediaElement play 2 video files and scroll/rewind both, simultaneously, without freezing/breaking whatever, for 24 hours? TIA

Comment: Did you try to use 2 files in MediaElement for 24 hrs?

Comment: No, not yet. Wanted to ask before rewriting code from WPFMediaKit

Comment: Without trying anything you get good response in stack overflow. Try something and post the problem that you are facing we will help you